# MarketingCloud AndroidSDK 8.0.0 | Tapping notification does not launch the app on Android 12

Tags: android, salesforce-sdk-android

Steps:

- Setup an Android project with targetSdkVersion 31
- In the same project, include version v8.0.0 of MarketingCloud: implementation "com.salesforce.marketingcloud:marketingcloudsdk:8.0.0"
- Setup MarketingCloud SDK using following instructions

  - "Full Control Customization" https://salesforce-marketingcloud.github.io/MarketingCloudSDK-Android/notifications/customize-notifications.html
- Compile the app in Android Studio and run the app on Android 12 Beta
- Send a test notification and tap it

Result:

- Activity does not start.
- Following log is printed in Logcat

> 10-06 10:18:22.977  1534  3091 E NotificationService: Indirect notification activity start (trampoline) from com.example.app blocked

---

By rewriting following code

```
builder.setContentIntent(
          NotificationManager.redirectIntentForAnalytics(
            context,
            PendingIntent.getActivity(
              context,
              Random().nextInt(),
              Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java),
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
            ),
            notificationMessage,
            true
          )
        )
```

with

```
builder.setContentIntent(
          PendingIntent.getActivity(
              context,
              Random().nextInt(),
              Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java),
              PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT
          )
        )
```

the app is launches correctly.

I think this problem is related to https://developer.android.com/about/versions/12/behavior-changes-12?hl=en#notification-trampolines

How to fix this problem?

Comment: Thank you.  Researching.

Comment: An immediate fix, obviously, would be to temporarily eliminate the `redirectForAnalytics()` wrapper of the `PendingIntent`, but this will affect the open analytics reported for the messages.  We're looking into a solution.

Comment: Alternatively, you could target `Android 30` which would work as-is today while we prepare a fix.

Comment: I'm going to leave targetSdkVersion at 30 until this issue is fixed. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please update to version 8.0.1 which has been released to address this issue.

Comment: I confirmed that the issue has been fixed on version 8.0.1. Thank you.

Comment: @Bill Mote ，Thank you very much! I am having a similar issue when using Firebase Messaging. Upgrading Firebase to the latest version should resolve the problem.